# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: registrationTokens is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I get the above error when I try and use `Firestore` to get data - I am trying to retrieve tokens from my db so I can send messages:

```
exports.getUsers = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    db.collection("users")
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            let registrationTokens = [];
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                let id = doc.id;

                registrationTokens.push(id);
            });
        });

    console.log(registrationTokens);

    const message = {
        data: { title: "Testing", body: "Test" },
        tokens: registrationTokens
    };

    messaging.sendMulticast(message).then(response => {
        console.log(response.successCount + " messages were sent successfully");
    });
});
```

Comment: You are declaring `registrationTokens` using `let` so it won't be available outside of that block. Also, your promise is getting rejected and there is no `catch` block to handle the rejected promises. Chain `catch` to `then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared registrationTokens inside of a promise, so it's not visible outside of it:

```
exports.getUsers = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    db.collection("users")
            .get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                 let registrationTokens = [];  
                 snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    let id = doc.id;

                    registrationTokens.push(id);
                });
                console.log(registrationTokens);

               // process the tokens
               const message = {
                 data: { title: "Testing", body: "Test" },
                 tokens: registrationTokens
               };

               messaging.sendMulticast(message).then(response => {
                   console.log(response.successCount + " messages were sent successfully");
              });


        });
    });
```

You need to remember that a promise executes asynchronous, so you need to wait for the results to appear.